# gitkraken doesn't automatically delete remote feature branches

Tags: git, git-flow, gitkraken

Using gitkraken with a gitflow-enabled repository and trying to figure out how to finish a feature branch in such a way so as to also delete from remote that feature branch if it exists. When you use the git-flow scripts this happens for you automatically. with gitkraken there doesn't seem to be any mentions on this in the manual. Am I missing something or is there no way to do this automatically with gitkraken?

Comment: Beside at least a `git config --global fetch.prune true`, I don't see any option in GitKraken either.

Comment: Getting this behavior also, wondering if I simply need to manually delete the remote branch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it automatically. They didn't think on remote branches when they develop git-flow plugin, as you can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTOgjQ9o4vQ).

You have to delete it manually after you finish your branch.